# Detecting Object Using Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

I am having 20000 images consisting of same kind of object in all the images. I wanted to draw a bounding box around the object of my interest using open cv python. Could you please advice on how to draw a box around the object of interest? 
I have been checking ORB, SIFT but all these draw a key point descriptors all over the image.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have some annotation of ROI where you want to draw BBOX ?

Answer (score 0):

Scale Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT) is used for **detecting** and **matching** feature points, means it just recognize the patterns in your images. If you want to have a box, circle or whatever frame around your object, you need to integrate it manually on top of your current approach. Lets say for e.g. taking center of your cluster as your rectangle center. In addition if you are interested you can have a look on NN-based methods as well, since they are widely used these days for pattern recognition algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Please, could you specify something more about the images? I see the two following scenarios:

1. if there is always a single object in the image you can use [a feature matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) and then a draw bounding box around all correctly matched features.
2. if you have multiple same objects in the image and there is no rotation or scaling you can use [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) (also [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)) over the whole image and identify the correlation peaks.
3. train a model for [deep object detection](https://towardsdatascience.com/r-cnn-fast-r-cnn-faster-r-cnn-yolo-object-detection-algorithms-36d53571365e), see for example [YOLO w. OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/), [SSD](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/ssd-object-detection-single-shot-multibox-detector-for-real-time-processing-9bd8deac0e06), [Faster RCNN](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/11/implementation-faster-r-cnn-python-object-detection/) and [Mask R-CNN w. OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/19/mask-r-cnn-with-opencv/)